# Does Spritekit (Swift) allow the use of two different Camera nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sprite-kit

So I'm working on a project that will require the use of two or more different camera nodes. The problem is that when I call for the second camera node to be activated and used, I get a signal SIGABRT error. I think I understand why this error is occurring, since there is already an active camera node. HOWEVER, my question is whether I can use two camera nodes in one scene, at different times and at different locations. Thank you for any help!

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  let cam1 = SKCameraNode()
  let cam2 = SKCameraNode()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(cam1)
    addChild(cam2)
    addChild(SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))

    cam1.position.x -= 100
    cam2.position.x += 100

    camera = cam1
  }

  func swapCam() {
    guard let cam = self.camera else { fatalError() }

    if cam === cam1 {
      camera = cam2
    } else if cam === cam2 {
      camera = cam1
    } else { fatalError() }
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swapCam()
  }
}
```

Tapping screen hops from left cam1 to right cam2, altering visibility of the built in "hello world" and the blue square I added.

Your issue has something to do with the SKS file (possibly wrong name?), or for putting the `!` at the end of SKCameraNode (not sure why that is there).

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! This has helped me tremendously! Thanks a lot! :)